# Implementing the wp json-rest api

Tags: api, json, rest-api

I have a client that wants to use the wp json-rest api to allow third-party sites to push custom posts (in this case property listings) up to our site.

I've been looking at using the wp json-rest api, since people seem to be having really good success with it and it looks like it would remove several headaches from my job.

There seems to be an abundance of information on what the json-rest api plugin can do, what you can use it for, things like that. But I've found very little information on actually implementing the api.

I don't have any experience building api clients, so I'm a little lost here.

Does anybody have some good resources for this? Or at least something to use as a starting point?

EDIT: I've also considered using Thermal, if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance!